# Android 5 (Lollipop): Is it possible to make the Background of a Notification transparent?

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there any way to make the Background of a Notification in Android transparent? I'm creating a Notification by using RemoteViews with a Layout and NotificationCompat:

```
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContent(rv);
```

The Background of the layout's LinearLayout is set to transparent. But in Lollipop the Background is always shown as white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way.

White color is the background of the *notification row*, not the notification itself. Your transparent `RemoteViews` is drawn on top of the notification row.

Technical details:

Appearance of notifications is defined in the [SystemUI package](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI). White color is defined in [colors.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/res/values/colors.xml#L79-L80), and is used in [ActivatableNotificationView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/ActivatableNotificationView.java#L155).

According to the source code, the only place where this color can be overriden is the [setTintColor method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/ActivatableNotificationView.java#L387-L390), but it is called only from [BaseStatusBar.java and only for media notifications](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java#L709-L714).

However even for media notificaitons transparent color does not work, probably because of [`setAlpha(1)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/ExpandableNotificationRow.java#L387-L388).